# How to get WooCommerce Product Categories and its children's children?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I added a Checkbox field in the `Product > Categories` on my dashboard and I want to display the categories that is being checked but I can't display the grand children of a parent category.

Here is my code:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
        $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
        $orderby      = 'name';  
        $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
        $title        = '';  
        $empty        = 0;
        $meta_key     = 'wh_meta_shop';

        $args = array(
               'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
               'orderby'      => $orderby,
               'show_count'   => $show_count,
               'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
               'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
               'title_li'     => $title,
               'hide_empty'   => $empty,
               'meta_key'     => $meta_key
        );
        echo '<ul class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">';
        echo '<ul class="product-categories">';
         $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
         foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
            if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
                $category_id = $cat->term_id;   
                echo '<li class="cat-parent"><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .' ('.$cat->count.')'.'</a>';

                $args2 = array(
                        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                        'child_of'     => 0,
                        'parent'       => $category_id,
                        'orderby'      => $orderby,
                        'show_count'   => $show_count,
                        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                        'title_li'     => $title,
                        'hide_empty'   => $empty
                );
                $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
                if($sub_cats) {
                  echo '<ul class="children">';
                    foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {

                        echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .' ('.$sub_category->count.')'.'</a></li>';
                    }   
                  echo '</ul>';
                }
            }       
        }
        echo '</li></ul></ul>';

      }
      add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

I created a shortcode for this since I want to put it on my sidebar widget.

**Edit**: In this code I am successfully getting the category and the first level children only.

I'm unable to display `test-category-inner`, see photo below:

[image]

Comment: You need to create another foreach inside the children category foreach loop to get grand children.....pass the parent id as children id to get grand child in new foreach loop

Comment: @Ranganathan.S Hmm, and if the grand children has a children again? Will need to make a foreach loop again? Just want to copy the query from the `WC_Widget_Product_Categories` widget and just kinda make a condition where the meta key is      $meta_key     = 'wh_meta_shop'; What do you think?